# Is there a way to sum indexed random variables on sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I want to make code of sum of Indexed Random variables, but can't find anyway for realizing it.

Is there any solutions?

I want to change below Indexed variables to randomized one.

```
import sympy as sp
import sympy.stats as ss
import numpy as np

x, i = sp.symbols("x i")
s = sp.Sum(sp.Indexed('x',i),(i,0,3))
```

Comment: It's not completely clear what you want to do. Can you clarify how you would use the result and what any expected output would look like?

Comment: sorry.

What I want to do is changing the above code into symbol 'x' to indexed random variable.
Want the code of calc Σx_i with all x_i are random variable.

Comment: It's still unclear. What would you do afterwards? What end result would you want?

Comment: I want variable 's' of the above code which is summation of Symbols. 
There is no afterwards. Just want summation of random variable symbols.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up after reading your comments:

```py
import sympy as sp
import sympy.stats as ss
import numpy as np
import string
from random import sample

i = sp.symbols("i")
x = sp.IndexedBase('x')
n = 3

# symbolic summation
s = sp.Sum(x[i], (i, 0, n))
expr = s.doit()
print(expr)
# out: x[0] + x[1] + x[2] + x[3]

# choose n+1 random characters from the lowercase alphabet
var_names = sample(string.ascii_lowercase, n+1)
# create symbols
symb = sp.symbols(var_names)
print(symb)
# out: [n, x, m, a]

# replace the elements of x with symbols
# NOTE: it is important to use sp.Matrix
final = expr.subs(x, sp.Matrix(symb))
print(final)
# out: a + m + n + x
```